# Is there a standard for using SAML tokens with RESTful services?

Tags: rest, saml

I'm using SAML tokens to authenticate against a set of REST-ful services, by putting the SAML token in the `Authorization` header.

I can't find anything out there that would suggest that there's a standard way to do this. For example, do I use:

```
Authorization: Bearer <EncryptedAssertion ...
```

or:

```
Authorization: Bearer PEVuY3J5cHRlZEFzc2VydGlvbiAuLi4=
```

or:

```
Authorization: SAML PEVuY3J5cHRlZEFzc2VydGlvbiAuLi4=
```

or something else?

Note that the first one doesn't work if the certificate has multiple name components (because the comma messes up the header parsing).

The fact that I'm using 'Bearer' doesn't say anything about the format of the token.

Apache CXF appears to use the third variant.

Which one is standard? Is there a standard? If not, is there a de-facto standard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard for custom auth schemes in HTTP is defined in the RFCs 2617 and 7235.

```
Authorization: scheme key="value", ...
```

I doubt there is a standard for your specific case, but I'd say this is acceptable:

```
Authorization: SAML bearer="PEVuY3J5cHRlZEFzc2VydGlvbiAuLi4="
```

Comment: Well divined, because it's not exactly obvious. To explain: RFC 2616 specifies `Authorization: credentials`, and RFC 2617 specifies `credentials = auth-scheme #auth-param` and `auth-param = token "=" ( token | quoted-string )`. Since RFC 2617 is about Basic/Digest authentication, it's easy to overlook section 1.2, where this stuff is specified.

Answer (score 4):

After doing quite a lot of research on this topic, I could not find any standard defining how to use a SAML Token in the Authorization header.

However CXF which is a quite famous Web-Serviec stack [supports SAML Token](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-saml.html) in the following manner:

```
Authorization: SAML eJydV1m....9fYTCPr=
```

OAuth2 also defines how to authenticate with SAML Token to receive a OAuth2 Access Token which can then be used to invoke another REST Service (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7522)

```
POST /token.oauth2 HTTP/1.1
Host: as.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Asaml2-bearer&
assertion=PHNhbWxwOl...[omitted for brevity]...ZT4
```

Comment: Thx for RFC7522, have you seen some practical code / examples / attribute content examples, etc ? Thx for post.